# Javascript string within a string

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'm very new to this, so I'm sorry if I cant explain myself properly. I'm running a website with a lightbox for images, inside the lightbox I embeded a link and what I want to do is that link to open a new pop-up window, but I've encountered a small problem on my code:

```
<a href="images/gallery/1.jpg" class="lytebox" data-title="<br /><a href='javascript:popUp('images/junk1.php')'/>Add a Comment</a>">
    <img src="images/thumbnails/1.jpg" border="0">
</a>
```

You see, when I get to the `'javascript:popUp('images/junk1.php')'` I've already used the apostrophes, so it doesn't load. I've been reading about strings being within strings and I've tried escaping it via \ but it doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Stringception. Sorry, try using &quot;

Comment: Embedding HTML like that is really horrid. Why not embed some data instead (like perhaps just `images/junk1.php`) and let a script take care of the rest of the content generation?

Comment: **+1000** to @Tomalak's comment.

Comment: No idea of what Tomalak's talking about. I know it's horrid. I've taken like 3 classes of php, I don't know much about this, and I need this for a test, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Use [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML). Something like this (not tested):

```
data-title="&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;javascript:popUp('images/junk1.php')&quot;/&gt;Add a Comment&lt;/a&gt;"
```

Answer (score 0):

ok.. how about you just change the call around a little.. not sure if this will work, but you could give it a try.

```
<a href="images/gallery/1.jpg" class="lytebox" data-title="<br /><a data-img='images/junk1.php' onclick='popUp(this.dataset.img)'/>Add a Comment</a>"><img src="images/thumbnails/1.jpg" border="0"></a>
```

or you can do as rob suggests...

```
<a href="images/gallery/1.jpg" class="lytebox" data-title="<br /><a href='javascript:popUp(&quot;images/junk1.php&quot;)'/>Add a Comment</a>">
    <img src="images/thumbnails/1.jpg" border="0">
</a>
```

Comment: Your answer would be OK if you replace `\"` with `&quot;` (<---Answer to question here).

Comment: ahh, i see your solution is probably better.